# Dynamically adding images break when document loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, d3.js, frontend

I am adding images to a div using JSON. At most, there are supposed to be only 5 images contained in the div. However, if I go to a different tab or if the document loses focus, the script adds more than 5 images to the div. Is it possible for the script to work correctly even if the document loses focus?

```
let temp = true; 

for (let key in orders) {
   if (orders[key].orders && orders[key].orders[0] && orders[key].orders[0].imageId && temp) {
      for (let i = 0; i < orders[key].orders.length; i++) {
         if (imageArray.indexOf(orders[key].orders[i].imageId) < 0) {
            imageArray.push(orders[key].orders[i].imageId);
            elem = document.createElement('img');
            elem.src = imageUrl + orders[key].orders[i].imageId + '._SR' + imageWidth + '_.jpg';
            if (checkboximage.checked == false) {
               elem.className = 'visToggle';
            }
            elem.addEventListener('load', function() {
               this.classList.add('imagesFadeIn');
            });
            elem.title = orders[key].orders[i].brand + ' - ' + orders[key].orders[i].style;
            rightImages.appendChild(elem);
            temp = false;
            break;
          }
       }
     } else {
       break;
   }
}

let imgs = rightImages.getElementsByTagName('img');
if (imgs.length > 5) {
   fadeOut(rightImages.firstElementChild);
   imageArray.shift();
}
```

Comment: Do you experience the issue in only a particular browser (on a particular OS)?

Comment: Currently happens in all browsers. I am working on OSX.